# Devise with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am making an app in rails 5 with devise. But after migration of user model which is used by devise the results are following:

```
User.new =>
    User id: nil,
    email: "",
    created_at: nil,
    updated_at: nil.
```

while It should be shown like:

```
User id: nil,
email: "",
encrypted_password: "",
reset_password_token: nil,
reset_password_sent_at: nil,
remember_created_at: nil,
sign_in_count: 0,
current_sign_in_at: nil,
last_sign_in_at: nil,
current_sign_in_ip: nil,
last_sign_in_ip: nil,
created_at: nil,
updated_at: nil,
name: nil
```

It means fields are not being create. but when I see the mysql database all the fields are being created inside users table. Then why it is not showing inside rails console?

Following are the schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160717050914) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer  "failed_attempts",        default: 0,  null: false
    t.string   "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: Did you `reload!` your rails console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `devise` overrides the inspect method, to not show their internal attributes. See this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/29142418bade74224d98bbf5bbcadfba181d5db9/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L119-L124

Anyway, they're there. Just not printed out in the `inspect` method.

To see all the attributes you can use:

```
user = User.first
user.attributes # => returns a hash containing all the attributes
```

Or e.g. to get the `current_sign_in_ip`:

```
user.current_sign_in_ip # => #<IPAddr: IPv4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/255.255.255.0>
```

Answer (score 2):

Devise restricts attributes like `encrypted_password` by overriding the default `inspect` method so that the critical information does not get exposed in API calls. So to override this, you need to override the `serializable_hash` method:

```
def serializable_hash(options = nil) 
  super(options).merge({ encrypted_password: encrypted_password }) 
end
```

Check out the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632699/rails-5-model-objects-not-showing-all-attributes).