# Rails & Devise: devise specific columns not showing up in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to use Devise on my User model but when I go into rails console and try `User.new` I only get:

```
irb(main):002:0> User.new
=> #<User id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Why are the devise columns not showing up?

CreateUsers migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

AddDeviseToUsers migration:

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Schema shows the columns are there:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, show us your `schema.rb`

Comment: @mrlew see edit thx

Comment: Can you try `User.new.attributes_name`?

Comment: undefined method `attributes_name' for #<User:0x007fe64a75a778>

Comment: `User.new.atrribute_names`, sry. Or `User.new.attributes`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Devise with rails 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419030/devise-with-rails-5)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a security feature that Devise has in order to restrict its attributes and the critical information it contains to be exposed to API calls.

You can however override this, you need to override serializable_hash method.

```
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :confirmable, :rememberable, :validatable

   ...

   protected

   def serializable_hash(options = nil) 
    super(options).merge(encrypted_password: encrypted_password, reset_password_token: reset_password_token) # you can keep adding attributes here that you wish to expose
  end

end
```

You can check http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Authenticatable where a constant is declared to blacklist attributes

```
BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION =[:encrypted_password, :reset_password_token, :reset_password_sent_at, :remember_created_at, :sign_in_count, :current_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_at, :current_sign_in_ip, :last_sign_in_ip, :password_salt, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at, :remember_token, :unconfirmed_email, :failed_attempts, :unlock_token, :locked_at]
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Is there any way to temporarily override this in the console, for example, to I'm implementing a "User last signed in" feature and would like a way of quickly viewing the devise cols if there's a quick and temporary way?

Comment: There is a small hack you can do in the same protected method like below

```
def serializable_hash(options = nil)
  super(options)
  options[:except] = []
end
```

For console purposes only :)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do it list all the attributes in the Rails console, it is easier to use `User.first.serializable_hash(force_except: true)`

See http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FAuthenticatable:serializable_hash

Answer (score 1):

Devise overrides the inspect method to not expose internal attibutes. You can try:

```
User.new.attributes
```

or

```
User.new.encrypted_password
```

(or whatever attribute you want)

You can check inspect method [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb)