# How does Rails know which attributes to show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Devise, and in `rails c` when I type `User.last` then it only shows `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, and `email` even though there are many attributes than that. Why does it do this? Do I have control on which default attributes it can show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security feature for not sharing critical information through API call and you can control it.

```
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord

   devise :database_authenticatable,...

   ...

   protected

   def serializable_hash(options = nil) 
    super(options).merge(reset_password_token) # you can keep adding attributes here that you wish to expose
  end

end
```

And you can get a list of all attributes with :

```
User.new.attributes
```

Full answer from another similar question :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754974/7970365