# Devise Invitable: Return a list of invitation tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, devise-invitable

I'm trying to add a button to my page that exports a list of the invited users with [Devise Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable). I want to include the invitation_tokens in that list.
`User.where.not(invitation_token: nil)` works to return the list of users, but it doesn't show the invitation_token there. `User.last.invitation_token` does return the invitation_token for that specific user, so I know the information is accessible.

Rather than looping through each invited user to retrieve its invitation_token, is there a way to get ActiveRecord to automatically return the token with a user? For example, `User.where.not(invitation_token: nil)` currently returns the following:

> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 6, email: "thecompany@example.org", created_at: "2022-05-09 11:37:07", updated_at: "2022-05-09 11:37:07"]>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a security measure in Devise that prevents sensitive information form being shown. Workarounds can be found here: [Rails & Devise: devise specific columns not showing up in rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754087/rails-devise-devise-specific-columns-not-showing-up-in-rails-console)